# Wrong OpenGL version being reported

Tags: drivers, gpu, amd-radeon, opengl

I have just bought a new AMD RX550 for deep learning purposes. However, when I tried to benchmark it some errors are being reported due to having old OpenGL version.

On the official manufacturers site, it is clearly stated that my GPU support 4.5 version yet my computer is showing it to be 1.1

The only way I have succeeded in a decent benchmark is to run the Vulkan ones be coz the GL1.1 benchmarks suck.

I have an AMD A4 apu with integrated graphics(obviously)& am running Win10_Lite. Could the 2 gpu be battling it out with the drivers?I have already tried DDU-ing the drivers but with no result. Is there any way to update the OpenGL?? Or am I facing I completely uninstalled driver?

UPDATE: I tried running Unigine Heaven benchmark(with DirectX) and it shows 0% GPU usage. Any fixes for that??

> product website == https://www.amd.com/en/products/graphics/radeon-rx-550

Comment: Have you installed, reinstalled or updated drivers for the graphics card? Have you tried on a stock (non "lite") version of Windows?

Comment: @Mokubai yep, I have tried re-installing. But I dont have any computer with Win10

Comment: A couple of options from https://windowsreport.com/opengl-problems-windows-10/ at a guess I'd try the `sfc` fix as it appears your system is broken. I'd be surprised at any recent APU that didn't support at least OpenGL 3 or 4+. Unless your computer is literally 15 years old the only likely issue is that your OS is severely broken, possibly due to being a "lite" version with part ripped out of it and your graphics card drivers relying on some of the missing parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was arising due to unforeseen clash of my integrated GPU and the discrete one. The solution was to enter the BIOS and change the default GPU to the one in Pcie slot. Now my whole rig works with better performance and resolution. Also note the fact that normal usage only takes 3-5% of GPU so there isn't much performance loss.....